# Coinbase API transferMoney not supporter anymore? Not Found error

Tags: javascript, node.js, coinbase-api

Im currently trying to transfer `Bitcoin` to `ETH` through two of my accounts using the official `Coinbase NodeJS Library`.

Ive basically copied the code from the [documentation](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#transfer-money-between-accounts) but included the currency argument which is required.
Heres my code:

```js
for (var currency in accounts) {
        client.getAccount(accounts[currency], function(err, account) 
        {
            if(err) {
                return;
            }           

            if(account.balance.amount > 0) {
                console.log('Trying to convert '+account.balance.amount+' '+account.balance.currency+' ('+accounts[account.balance.currency]+') to ETH ('+accounts['ETH']+')');
                account.transferMoney({'type':'transfer','to': accounts['ETH'],'amount': account.balance.amount,'currency':account.balance.currency}, function(err, tx) {
                    if(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    console.log(tx);
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

**Accounts** is just an object including the account ids of my currencies.
Ive checked the values multiple times and the `console.log` is also giving me correct values however the `transferMoney method` is giving me the following error:

```
0|app  | NotFound: Not found <br>
0|app  |     at handleHttpError <br>(/root/app/node_modules/coinbase/lib/errorHandler.js:46:15)<br>
0|app  |     at Request.onPost [as _callback] <br>(/root/app/node_modules/coinbase/lib/ClientBase.js:179:10)<br>
0|app  |     at Request.self.callback <br>(/root/app/node_modules/coinbase/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)<br>
0|app  |     at Request.emit (events.js:203:13)<br>
0|app  |     at Request.<anonymous> <br>(/root/app/node_modules/coinbase/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)<br>
0|app  |     at Request.emit (events.js:203:13)<br>
0|app  |     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> <br>(/root/app/node_modules/coinbase/node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)<br>
0|app  |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:291:20)<br>
0|app  |     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:15)<br>
0|app  |     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1154:12)<br>
```

The only problem I can imagine is that coinbase doesnt support the  `transferMoney method` anymore which would kinda suck.

Any idea why its giving me the error, is there anything wrong with my code or is it just a problem with the `coinbase api`?